# Redirect directory index to the actual page?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a folder called "screenshots" but "screenshots" is also the name of one of the subpages on my website.

As in example.com/screenshots will lead me to the directory index instead of leading me to my example.com/screenshots subpage.

Could anyone give me the htaccess code that allows me to redirect my screenshots directory index page to the actual screenshot page?

EDIT: The web server is Apache, screenshots is a generated in my Atom editor as an HTML file and uploaded onto my website through FileZilla. There is an /index.html page but that is outside of my "screenshots" folder.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As it stands, this question is unanswerable since you haven't given any information about the environment.  What web server? How is the subpage `screenshots` being generated? Is there an `index.html` file in `/screenshots` or is it a servlet or JSP?  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question and will look more into the links you provided

Comment: I guess you need turn directory slash off.use(DirectorySlash Off) in .htaccessfile

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the directory slash using DirectorySlash directive.

Add the following line to your htaccess :

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This will allow you to rewrite screenshot ( **without a trailing slash** ) to /screenshot.extension.

/screensho/ ( **with a trailing slash** ) will allow you to access the dir

You can use the following code to redirect /screenshot to /screenshot.php

```
DirectorySlash off

RedirectMatch 302 ^/screenshot$ /screenshot.php
```